# oracle weblogic ve el registro de la aplicación?

Tags: java, weblogic

¿cómo te gustaría saber si hay una forma de ver el System.out.put que puse en java, si puedes verlo en algún log de weblogic?

Comment: Si, los system.output van hacia los logs del servidor weblogic. Desde la consola de administración los puedes ver pero es medio complicado buscarlos. Al menos, para mí, me resulta más fácil abría un terminal, conectarme al weblogic , voy al directorio logs y ahí se encuentran dos archivos <nombre_servidor_weblogic>.log y .out. por ejemplo: AdminServer.log y. AdminServer.out. En los out encontrarás tu sout.

Comment: De manera predeterminada los logs del servidor se encuentra en DOMAIN_NAME\servers\SERVER_NAME\logs\SERVER_NAME.log donde DOMAIN_NAME es el nombre del directorio donde has colocado el dominio y SERVER_NAME el nombre del servidor. [docs.oracle.com/logging_services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13739/logging_services.htm#WLLOG130)